# How to reshape dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below picture shown, how to effectively get all value with ":" in the cell and create a new dataframe? For instance, "cnt:1" shall be converted to "1"; "ack:dsn:113" shall be converted to "113", etc.
[image]

Comment: Can you please share what have you done so far?

Comment: @Aritesh, I am new to pandas and want to find the most effective way to reshape my big dataset (hundred of thousands entries) with it.

Comment: Answers have been provided below, just wondering if you have read from a json, and if yes, there are better ways to read it

Comment: Actually the original log file is in txt format. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rsplit` with limit 1 and select second values of `list`s:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.rsplit(':', 1)[1])
```

Or:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.rsplit(':', 1).str[1])
```

---

```
print (df)
   dsn cnt retry rssir lqir rssif lqif
0  113   1     1   -24    6   -49    5
1  114   2     1   -24   10   -49   15
2  115   3     1   -24    5   -59   14
3  116   4     1   -24    8   -58   11
4  117   5     1   -24   12   -57   14
```

Or simplier as pointed [Anton vBR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50480760/how-to-reshape-dataframe-with-pandas#comment87974850_50480818):

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.rsplit(':')[-1])

df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.rsplit(':').str[-1])
```

Comment: because first column have multiple `:`

Comment: Yeah but OP wants last value always, ie str[-1]

Comment: @AntonvBR IIUC `rsplit` with  a limit of `1` is more efficient than splitting the entire string into more parts than necessary.  So `'a:b:c'.rsplit(':', 1)[-1]` is better than `'a:b:c'.split(':')[-1]`

Comment: Thank you guys, my dataset is a bit huge (+100,000 entries), then i need to find the way to handle it effectively. rsplit with limit is better.

Answer (score 2):

With [`pandas.DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) using `regex=True`

```
df.replace('(.*:)', '', regex=True)

   dsn cnt retry rssir lqir rssif lqif
0  113   1     1   -24    6   -49    5
1  114   2     1   -24   10   -49   15
2  115   3     1   -24    5   -59   14
3  116   4     1   -24    8   -58   11
4  117   5     1   -24   12   -57   14
```

---

More cumbersome with Numpy string functions

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import rsplit

pd.DataFrame(
    np.array(
        [t[1] for t in rsplit(
            df.values.ravel().astype(str), ':', 1
        )]
    ).reshape(df.shape),
    df.index, df.columns
)

   dsn cnt retry rssir lqir rssif lqif
0  113   1     1   -24    6   -49    5
1  114   2     1   -24   10   -49   15
2  115   3     1   -24    5   -59   14
3  116   4     1   -24    8   -58   11
4  117   5     1   -24   12   -57   14
```